# Future posting with dateCreated in Wordpress via XMLRPC in Ruby

Tags: ruby, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm reaching the end of my tether trying to schedule a new post through Wordpress' XMLRPC interface from Ruby.

I am creating a new **Time** object and filling it with my date and time, I then call **.xmlschema** to get a datetime string in the correct format for Wordpress' XMLRPC interface.

Unfortunately, Wordpress treats this as a string, and I can't work out how to get the xmlrpc.php to treat it as an object; really can't get my head around it.

Calling the *metaWeblog.newPost* method, and sending:

```
{:title => 'Foo', :post_status => 'publish', :dateCreated => my_date.xmlschema}
```

to Wordpress.

Anyone been through this before?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what you are actually sending (the post data)? The date should be encapsulated in `<dateTime.iso8601></dateTime.iso8601>`, not in `<string></string>`. The WordPress Trac has [a similar report](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6612).

Comment: Jan - interestingly I just changed my_date.xmlschema to my_date (so it is a ruby datetime data type), and it just worked fine...

A bit embarrassing if this is the cause of all my problems.